# How to switch between the list of tests and the output/console inside the run window using the keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

When I run tests and open the run window using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> shortcut, I find the cursor either in the list of tests on the left or in the console/output on the right.I would like to switch back and forth between the two using the keyboard only.

I have searched in the keymap, the online help and have [posted in the RubyMine forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451605) but could not find an answer.

Experimenting with <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>/<kbd>Tabs</kbd>/<kbd>Numbers</kbd> combos did not help.

The window parts are not individually selectable in the window switcher (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

I am using RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you could write a plugin for this? For bounty +200, I might be willing to help...

Comment: I hoped for a core functionality here, but anyways the question is bounty-eligible in 2 days. If with 'help' you mean 'implement', I'm interested :)

Comment: By the way did you try just plain `tab`?

Comment: among other things, yes. If you find a key combination that works or can be made to work, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Tab works for me (intellij 13.01). The thing is, I cant see a cursor when I tab to the console/output, but if I use shift-up/down to I can see that the console definitely has the focus. Tab from the console puts focus to the list of tests on the left. Does this work similarly for you?

Comment: Cool, it does not work with RubyMine 5.4, but with RubyMine 6 it does. (I dont have IJ installed on my work PC, so cannot confirm ATM). It works only when the tests list is in focus initially. If the cursor is in the console, tabbing has no effect. So this was a core functionality after all, nice. Please post your answer, you've got my vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, using Intellij 13.0.1, or a derived IDE, like RubyMine 6 <kbd>Tab</kbd> *should* work, with certain nuances.

When the focus is on the list of tests initially, I am able to tab between the list of tests and the console - the thing is, I cant see a cursor when I tab to the console/output, but if I use shift-up/down to I can see that the console definitely has the focus.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again puts focus back to the list of tests on the left.

If the focus is in the console/output initially, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> has no effect and I have to use the mouse to 'escape'.

Earlier versions, based on ItelliJ 12 seem not to support this feature.

I hope this helps.